# Send GPS location when APP is not running (Phonegap)

Tags: cordova, gps

I am wondering if it is possible that my app sends the GPS location to the server every minute even though the app is not running?

And if yes, how I can realize this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean tracking GPS location when app is in background, there sure is a plugin. checkout,

[cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

Comment: This plugin is now demo-only for android and required a license key.